# How to express the idea of "not exactly" humorously?

Tags: одним-словом

> Хотя, полагаю, скромностью мы не отличаемся...

In English, you can use the phrase "not exactly" to humorously express the idea of "far from" or "hardly", as in: "we are not exactly {= far from} known for being modest". It's almost tantamount to saying: "we're well-known for bragging about stuff".

The way the sentence stands now, I suppose it does not convey this idea. I wonder how you should paraphrase it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to show you the difference in translation of the same word and to prove that everything depends on the context. And there's no unique solution. You can analyse the following examples.

1 Not exactly what I had in mind.
**Не совсем то**, что я имел в виду.  ☰

2.We are not exactly imbeciles in money matters.
Что касается денег, то мы **не такие уж** дураки в этих делах.  ☰

3. It's not exactly a cultural center like Paris.
   Это место **не назовёшь** культурным центром вроде Парижа.  ☰  ☰
4. He's not exactly a grub. 
   Он **не особенно** корпит над учебниками.  ☰ ☰
5. We're not exactly driving fast. 
   Я **бы не сказал**, что мы быстро едем.  ☰
6. She's not exactly a workaholic. 
   На работе она **точно не** горит.  ☰
7. Heavy metal is not exactly my bag. *
   Тяжелый рок - это **не для меня**.  ☰
   ☰
8. I'm not exactly mad about this job. 
   Я **не в восторге** от этой работы.  ☰
9. They're not exactly killing themselves. 
   Они **не слишком** утруждают себя.  ☰
10. She's not exactly what you call stupid. 
    Я **не хочу сказать, что** она глупа.  ☰
    ☰
11. He's not exactly a jerk but comes close. 
    Он **не то чтобы** дурак, но что-то в этом роде.  ☰

As for your sentence, I would say "Ну, от скромности мы не умрем..."
It is translated "We are not exactly to die from modesty..."

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly humorous, but with irony and a modicum of smug

> Хотя, полагаю, (что) мы не то чтобы уж `очень`/`чересчур`/`страшно`* скромные
>   Хотя, полагаю, (что) не такие уж мы (прям(о)) `и`/`все из себя`* скромные

<sup>* alternatives</sup>

These have a more closely related English equivalents, but for the collocation in question they will do as well.

Comment: Опечатка: надо череСчур.

Comment: спасибо, исправил

Answer (score 2):

I think it's *possible* to deny 'exactness' in Russian, with a similar effect:

> Скромность, полагаю, **не вполне** нам свойственна.
>
> Скромность, полагаю, **не главное** наше достоинство.
>
> Наша скромность, полагаю, **не всегда** бывает заметна.
>
> Скромность, которой мы так славимся, я полагаю, нам **не всегда** удаётся
>   проявить.
>
> Наше природное стремление к скромности, я бы сказал, **не во всех
>   случаях** достигает цели.

Answer (score 2):

I think, the most literal and universal match would be ***"не особенно"***:

*"Мы, вообще-то, **не особенно** скромные."* - literally means "we are not particularly modest", the implied meaning usually is "not modest at all".

"Learning Russian isn't exactly easy" => *"Русский язык **не особенно** лёгок в изучении"* (literally "not particularly but still kinda easy", but we probably meant to say "not easy at all").

There's also "[что-либо] **не является сильной стороной** [чего-либо или кого-либо]" or "[что-либо] **не является** [чьей-либо] **сильной стороной**". For example:

*"Скромность **не является** моей **сильной стороной**"* (literally "not my strong side", the implied meaning is "not present among my sides at all").

*"Комфорт водителя **не является сильной стороной** трактора "Беларусь".*

You can also use "не относится к сильным сторонам" instead:

*"Комфорт водителя **не относится к сильным сторонам** трактора "Беларусь".*

You can use that speaking about the Russian language, as in the example above, but the sentence gets really clumsy and somewhat unnatural: "Лёгкость в изучении **не является сильной стороной (не относится к сильным сторонам)** русского языка."

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, I never thought *hardly* could take humorous modalities in English.

Also, English humour differs from the Russian one (as usually emotions among different languages do), and mild irony doesn't usually work in the latter. Here are some options in different registeres, from official/high and down to conversational;

***Называть себя скромными было бы слишком/слишком нескромно.***

***Скромность нам чужда.***

***Мы чураемся (своей/собственной) скромности.***

***Своей скромности мы стесняемся / Мы стесняемся собственной скромности.***

***Нам стыдно, что мы такие скромные.***

***Извините за скромность.***

***Скромность - это не для нас / это не про нас.*** (a cliche)

***Скромность - это не наше.***

***Скромность - это лишнее.*** (with a disapproving modality; usually said to a third person in a questioning modality, see also on 'we' / 'us' as a second person pronoun).

UPD: In my opinion, the most exact version of 'we are not exactly/far from known for being modest' would be ***Скромностью мы [определённо / точно] не славимся / не отличаемся.*** (higher register / lower register)

Comment: Hi. It's not "hardly", but the phrase "not exactly", that you can use humorously. :D

Comment: @alone-Zee Which reminds me of the immortal 'Borat' episode. I've made some amendments in my answer, though.

Comment: For instance, if you say "Learning Russian is**n't exactly** easy", you may be thinking that "Learning Russian is hard!".

Comment: @alone-Zee *Exactly.*